# Find Max() updated time for a group of users

Tags: mysql, mariadb, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, max

Database is MariaDB 10.3.25

I have 2 columns that are relevant:

UserID and LastUpdate

UserID consists of user@domain
LastUpdate is a date field.

Here is my issue - I have the current query:

```
select a.UserID, 
substring_index(a.UserID, '@', -1), 
max(a.lastupdate) 
from MyTable a 
group by a.UserID
having max(a.lastupdate) < '2020-03-31'
```

This shows all the Users that haven't updated in just over a year and the domain. However there is the following scenario that I want to account for:

UserID LastUpdate
A@A.com 2020-08-16
B@A.com 2019-05-16
C@A.com 2021-05-05

With the current query, B@A.com will be captured, and therefore domain A.com will be captured as not in use, but the user C@A.com is still active - I want to do a Max(a.lastupdate) but have it grouped by  `substring_index(a.UserID, '@', -1)`
but also spit out all the users for that domain.
I'm sure the answer is starring me in the face...

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to know both the inactive users and the inactive domains? Something like: `UserID | Domain | LastUserUpdate | LastDomainUpdate`?

Comment: I don't need to know the Last domain update - I just need to know all the UserIDs if none of the UserIDs grouped by the domain have used it in ~ the last 12 months

Comment: After reading your comment above, I edited my answer to return all of the user_id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably the following. This solution makes use of the `GENERATED COLUMN` functionality of MariaDB >= 10.3 (also in MySQL >= 5.7) - it's really very handy for queries like this - it also makes the query **much** more readable.

All the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=cf2d2ad5595db0f0f378017fe36b306e):

```
CREATE TABLE login
(
  user_id VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  last_login TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  domain_name VARCHAR (255) 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_id, '@', -1))) VIRTUAL,  -- can be STORED

  INDEX (last_login),  -- indexing up to you if you have lots of data...
  INDEX (domain_name)
);
```

And then some sample records:

```
INSERT INTO login (user_id, last_login) 
VALUES 
('pol@blah.ie', '2021-03-06'), 
('xyz@blah.ie', '2021-03-06'), 
('abc@blah.ie', '2021-03-06'), 
('pqr@blah.ie', '2021-03-06'), 
('rst@blah.ie', '2021-03-06'),
('fred@xyz.ie', '2020-03-20'), 
('bill@xyz.ie', '2020-03-15'), 
('mary@xyz.ie', '2020-03-14'), 
('joe@xyz.ie', '2020-02-12'), 
('mike@xyz.ie', '2020-01-31');
```

And then run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT domain_name, MAX(last_login) AS last_login_by_domain
  FROM login
  GROUP BY domain_name
) AS tab
WHERE last_login_by_domain < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
ORDER BY last_login_by_domain DESC;

-- DESC because you might want to deal with recent ones more urgently?
-- renew subscription... whatever
```

Result:

```
domain_name   last_login_by_domain       
     xyz.ie    2020-03-20 00:00:00
```

This works on all versions of MariaDB >= 10.3 from dbfiddle.uk (a great resource) and also on versions of MySQL >= 5.7.

It also works when MySQL's ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY set! This is **very** important - if that variable is not set, queries can (and **[will](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/05/13/solve-query-failures-regarding-only_full_group_by-sql-mode/)** - also see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)) return erroneous results (see my comment to the other answer to this question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/291005/find-max-updated-time-for-a-group-of-users/291025#comment569270_291019)).

For an example, just look at the bottom of the fiddle, where I've pointed out the problem that arose with the other answer in this (relatively **simple**) case - in a complex statement, this issue can lead to all sorts of hard to find bugs - caveat emptor!

### EDIT: After looking at the comments on the question ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=552ceb49b566495823a102b95c45c063)):

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM login
WHERE domain_name IN
(
  SELECT domain_name FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      domain_name, MAX(last_login) AS last_login_by_domain
    FROM login
    GROUP BY domain_name
  ) AS tab
  WHERE last_login_by_domain < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
);
```

Result:

```
user_id
bill@xyz.ie
fred@xyz.ie
joe@xyz.ie
mary@xyz.ie
mike@xyz.ie
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that is an amazingly in-depth response - I had tried to do it without multiple sub-queries, but I guess I should have gone down that option.

Answer (score 1):

See if its what you want

```
-- this main query retrieve all users under the subquery domain
SELECT a.UserID
    , substring_index(a.UserID, '@', -1)
    , MAX(a.lastupdate)
FROM MyTable a
WHERE substring_index(a.UserID, '@', -1) IN (

    -- this subquery search all domain inactive in last 12 months
    SELECT substring_index(a.UserID, '@', -1) AS domain
    FROM MyTable a
    GROUP BY substring_index(a.UserID, '@', -1)
    HAVING MAX(a.lastupdate) < '2020-03-31'

)
ORDER BY substring_index(a.UserID, '@', -1), a.lastupdate
```

Comment: Take a look at the bottom of my fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=cf2d2ad5595db0f0f378017fe36b306e) - it shows what happens when you don't have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` set...

Comment: I tried that and initially didn't get the right ouput - but when I added the correct Group By's that also worked.

Answer (score 0):

(The main Question is handled by subqueries, as seen in other Answers.  Here are some side issues.)

```
INDEX(UserID, lastupdated)
```

will help performance.

And why not do

```
HAVING MAX(a.lastupdate) < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

So that you don't have to keep changing the query.